# What’s the specification for msFullscreenEnabled

Tags: javascript, dom, specifications, msdn

MDN has [the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Other_information) to say about fullscreenEnabled:

> The `fullscreenEnabled` attribute tells you whether or not the document is currently in a state that would allow fullscreen mode to be requested.

I take this to mean: the property holds whenever requesting full screen is possible.

Microsoft has almost identical wording about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Returns `true` if a document lets elements be displayed in full-screen mode. Otherwise it returns `false`.

However, on the MSDN [detail page about the property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj879313.aspx), there’s the following, contradictory, information:

> Flag that indicates whether or not an element is currently in full-screen mode.

and

> Because this property only returns true when an element is currently in full-screen mode, it shouldn't be used for feature detection.

What’s up with that?

*Update*

My tests show that the `msFullscreenEnabled` property on IE 11 indeed yields false negatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  must understand that each browser has it's own specific implementation of `fullscreenEnabled`.

> Because the W3C Fullscreen specification isn't final, most browser
>   vendors prefix the API.  It's a good idea to have a single function that requests full-screen mode across all prefixes.

However, somewhere along the way the W3 fullscreen API document(18 November 2014) became discontinued in favor of the WHATWG's work on a [Fullscreen API specification](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/) - ongoing.

---

**Internet Explorer** did not implement it prior to version 11. In IE11 it was in the experimental stage (named as `msFullscreenEnabled`). Microsoft Edge and beyond chooses to go with the name `fullscreenEnabled`. **The false negatives** for `msFullscreenEnabled` , it being in an experimental stage, shouldn't be unexpected.

**Mozilla Firefox**'s fullscreenEnabled is also experimental. It is enabled by default after Firefox 10. It's syntax is actually `mozFullScreenEnabled`.
Same principle for `webkit`.

`mozFullScreenEnabled`'s [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/mozFullScreenEnabled) of it is :

> Reports whether or not full-screen mode is available. Full screen mode is available only for a page that has no windowed
>   plug-ins in any of its documents, and if all  elements which
>   contain the document have their allowfullscreen attribute set.

which is in accordance with the current Fullscreen API specs which [mentions](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#api):

> `fullscreenEnabled` 
>   Returns true if document has the ability to display
>   elements fullscreen and fullscreen is supported, or false otherwise.

---

My guess is MS followed the discontinued W3C fullscreen api doc which changed at some point and ended up with a different spec from the current working api.
The fact that i have only found the W3C discontinued document reference on the the [Microsoft Fullscreen API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265028(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to support this.

I believe what's mentioned in the [Microsoft Fullscreen API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265028(v=vs.85).aspx) will be updated in [fullscreenenabled property description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn254938(v=vs.85).aspx). But I haven't quite gotten my hands on an Edge browser yet so I can't say for sure if it's the spec that's wrong or the implementation.

---

You could also take a look at the background/necessity of the HTML 5 full screen API [here](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2014/11/13/how-to-implement-html5-full-screen-api/) and browser support of the API [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=fullscreen).

Comment: Edge has since unprefixed the property but the detail page and the overview page on MSDN still contradict one another. I have not tried to see what Edge actually does.